# List of Active Open Source Projects built by Adobe AIR/Flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, open-source, air

Could someone share list of active and popular open source Rich Internet Applications or desktop application (not library or framework) that are built by Adobe AIR/Flex? The popularity and quality I am looking for are something like Azureus/Vuze (Java), XBMC etc. Can't find good example from http://www.riaforge.org.

Thanks.

Comment: All of the Flex Open Source projects I know of are libraries / Utilities for helping developers build applications.  I don't know of any complete applications [beyond sample ones built by Adobe]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out sourceforge too: http://sourceforge.net/search/?q=adobe+air

Comment: I just took a look at SourceForge for Open Source Flex apps and found [this little guy](http://sourceforge.net/projects/flexapps/) by James Ward.  Which is awesome, because his stuff is pretty good!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure, you will have also a look at GitHub:
https://github.com/search?langOverride=&q=Flex&repo=&start_value=1&type=Repositories

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are looking for exactly, but you might want to check out Tour de Flex which has a bunch of great quick examples http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/tourdeflex.html that offer a great primer. I also always find myself visiting http://blog.flexexamples.com/ , which offers a large variety of source. Outside of that site, flash/flex has a bunch of other flex evangelist that also have some pretty comprehensive sites.

Hope that helps.

Comment: As in my question, list of active and complete RIA/desktop application instead of code examples. Thanks.